# Limit Excerpt length in Custom Post types and remove the brackets

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am trying to limit the excerpt length on my custom posts to 100 characters and also remove the brackets at the end of the sentence. I've tried all sorts of solutions listed on Stack Overflow and nothing has worked thusfar.

I have 4 custom post types: Detox, Recipes, Movement, Lifestyle

[Post Feed Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drfiz.png)

Comment: Please add your code then only we can check the issue

Comment: What code in particular are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

please use the below code to remove the brackets.

```
function remove_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return '';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'remove_excerpt_more');
```

and use the below code to limit the length of the excerpt.

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
global $post;
if ($post->post_type == 'post')
  return 25;
else if ($post->post_type == 'custom_post_type')
  return 15;
else
  return 25;
}
   return 20;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately neither of those have solved the problem. It is suggested code that I have tried before and is doesn't seem to have any effect on the blog posts at all.

https://utopia-rising.com/